# Symfony3 handling sensitive data in url params

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with Symfony3. I have a route with some params in `routing.ym`l i.e:

```
test_route
    path: /test/{username}/{password}
```

in my Controller I would pick these up like this:

```
        $username = $request->get('username');
        $password = $request->get('password');
```

Now would process according to the expected outcome anyway.

I am just wondering handling username and password through url is not safe? So how would I pick up username and password entered by user...? I know there is a bundle such as FOSUserBundle etc but I dont want to use any bundle at this point.

Comment: Are you familiar with https?  It is basically the only way to protect any data being sent between the browser and the server.  Nothing that Symfony can do about it.  SSL certificates are coming down in price and every site should have one.

Comment: ok so as of dev perspective the way I would handle it its fine..? it would be the ssl that would actually protect the data send in url...?, even if the param would be plain text...?

Comment: Correct.  Using https encrypts everything.  No need to do anything more on the development side.  You should definitely invest some time in learning the basics of internet security.  Even if your site is not really a hacker's target, people tend to use the same password for multiple sites and thus you should protect them.

Comment: So in general dough handling users sensitive details in url is ok? and in this case I belief all hosting companies and their servers are protected by ssl?

Comment: Nope. Nope. Nope.  You need to do some research.  Try connecting to your site using https.  More than likely it won't work unless you have installed and configured a ssl certificate specifically for your site.

Comment: Nope Nope Nope meas it is not ok to send sensitive data in url..? if not how then in symdony world? And ye maybe you know some good read about ssl good I mean easy to understand.

Comment: The nope nope nope refers to the extremely dangerous assumption that https/ssl is provided by default.  It is not.  Once you have it then you are fine.  Well mostly.  State sponsored hackers and large companies like google can still read the data but not much you can do about that.

Comment: Good god no! Never put sensitive data inside URL? Username: Sure, Password: Never, Session ID: Never, Token: Sure, if short lived...

Comment: Ok thank you guys, @JovanPerovic so if not url then how..? thx

Comment: @Tomazi: If password is to be transported then do the `POST` request instead of `GET` and **always** utilize `HTTPS`

Comment: @JovanPerovic is right. Don't ever sent a password in a URL. Also don't sent usernames in the URL as well. Then it is possible to determine "usernames" of the system, an then with the "username" a hacker might gather this and attempt to break into your site. Never give out information about your system in the URL where possible to avoid this.